# Swagger-PHP OpenAPI nested route

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, openapi

**Controller**

```
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

class ApiPersonController
{
    /**
     * @OA\Post(
     *     path="/add",
     *     responses={
     *          @OA\Response(
     *              response=202,
     *              description="Request has been accepted and is being processed"
     *          )
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function add()
    {

    }
}
```

What must I add to the doc comment of `ApiPersonController` so that the swagger.json generated by [Zircote/Swagger-PHP](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php#usage-from-php) gives this output?

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: 'My API'
  version: 1.1.0
paths:
  /person/add:
    post:
      operationId: 'ApiPersonController::add'
      responses:
        '202':
          description: 'Request has been accepted and is being processed'
```

Specifically, **how do I get all routes inside ApiPersonController to have `/person` added to them without specifying `/person` inside each route**

I'm looking for something like the following, but this just adds `/person` and `/add` separately to my swagger.json

```
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\PathInfo(path="/person")
 **/
class ApiPersonController
{
    ...
```

Comment: I believe you will have to put it there manually as per zircote [example](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore-3.0/controllers/Store.php). This is because of the decision made during design of version 3 - now the path contains only base path, endpoint path and query parameters. You are free to write your own extension for zircote’ library, of course.